# jQuery multiple .load() stripping out ColdFusion Ajax controls?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am running itno a jquery/coldfusion problem, demonstrated by the following files:

cflayout.cfm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<cflayout name="tabtest" type="tab">
  <cflayoutarea name="tab1" title="tab1" >
          <span>This is tab 1</span>
        </cflayoutarea>
        <cflayoutarea name="tab2" title="tab2" >
          <span>This is tab 2</span>
        </cflayoutarea>
</cflayout>
</html>
```

cfcontent.cfm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<cfajaximport tags="cfform,cflayout-tab">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--commenting out the jquery loader is for when loading via cftest.html
    When run on its own, uncomments it-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#fcontent").load("cflayout.cfm");
         }); 
</script>
fcontent:
<div id="fcontent">
</div> 
</html>
```

cftest.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>CFLayout Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#fdiv").load("cfcontent.cfm");
     });
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="fdiv">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In real life the cfcontent.cfm file acts as a triage page that re-directs flow to other pages.

Now cflayout.cfm runs fine by itself, as does cfcontent.cfm. But trying to load cftest.html and the tab control disappears, as if through multiple use of jquery .load() has "stripped-out" the control.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is this a known issue? As the actual .html in this case is inherited I can't replace it with a .cfm file and using cfinclude instead.

Any suggestions on how I should re-structure my approach?

Comment: you might need to use cfajaximport on your parent page to make sure the scripts for your cflayout are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with jQuery, whenever you load new information to a page you'll generally lose the javascript controls for new elements unless you actively watch for those changes.  In this case you'll want to make sure that the javascript for the ajax created by CF is included and ran when the page is loaded.  With other jQuery pages I just have to bind the new elements.  With Coldfusion ajax controls I'm not sure how to help you since we've moved away from them here.  They were too big of a hassle at times.  I understand that's probably not an option for you.

You may consider this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(".myTargetDIV").html('<cfoutput><cfinclude template="myColdFusion.cfm"></cfoutput>');
```